# Install intel haxm android

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, haxm

Hi everyone i am trying to install Intel HAXM to work with eclipse for Android developer . 
I got error when i want to open the Android Virtual Device as show bwlow

[AVD manager error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkDIr.jpg)

and i am trying to install Emulator Acceleration but also show it not compatible with windows 10 as show below

[eror2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdOUz.jpg)

can anyone help me to fix the problem ? below are some details about the specification of my PC.

[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwEwl.jpg)

[cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COO2T.jpg)

[general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piLXY.jpg)

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try Hyper-V. it may help, in your case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bios set up while your computer starts in pressing boot key. Then  find Intel Virtualisation Technology and Enable it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi dear , it's work now but another message show now

Comment: [2018-08-15 13:01:45 - Dex Loader] Failed to load D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\28.0.2\lib\dx.jar
[2018-08-15 13:01:45 - JetSkiOman] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

Comment: Go to sdk manager and try to find HAXM and download it and then try , that may help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version HAXM version 7.2.0, uninstall it and install version 7.1.0. Doing this solved my problem.

[Link for version 7.1.0 windows edition](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.1.0/haxm-windows_v7_1_0.zip)